# Create publisher from string parameter dynamically

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I searched on the internet without any luck.

Is there any way in ROS/C++ to solve the following problem? :

I want to have a launch file in which I want to specify a parameter `tags` in the following way:

`<param name="tags" type="string" value="1, 15, 189"/>`

and then in the `.cpp` file associated I would like to create different publishers (or maybe it is easier to create an array of publishers) which will publish on the topics:

`/pose/tag_1` `/pose/tag_15` `/pose/tag_189`

(the conversion from string to an array of ints is not an issue. I know how to do it.

Of course, I want that the `tags` parameter can be changed from the launch file and therefore the *creation* of the topics is in some way dynamic.

Thanks for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284821/create-publisher-from-string-parameter-dynamically/) by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can access ROS param's within a node using rosparam: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server

You could also pass in the topic names via args or params in the node's local namespace. See http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node

---

Example:

```
<node name="my_node" pkg="my_node_pkg" type="my_node" 
  args="tag_1, tag_2, tag_189" 
/>
```

or

```
<node name="my_node" pkg="my_node_pkg" type="my_node" 
  <param name="tags" value="1, 15, 189" />
/>
```

---

**Edit:**
Inside your node, once you've retrieved the args/params, you can do something like this (untested):

```
...
// Assuming some iterable object 'tags' containing your args/param in some format
ros::NodeHandle n;

std::vector<ROS::Publisher> publisherVec;
for (int i=0; i<tags.size(); i++) {
    publisherVec.push_back(<n.advertise<std_msgs::String>(tags[i], 100));
}
...
```

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/20381/fabbro/) on 2018-03-08**:
Hi, thanks for the fast reply but this is not what I asked. I know how to write the parameters in the launch file. My problem was to then create some sort of array of publishers.

Anyway, I solved my problem I think/hope and I will post the solution soon.
Thanks again.